# Running "svn revert ./ -R" outputs a "Reverted [file]" message for every file even if only a single file actually had modifications

Tags: svn

We use SVN heavily at my job and we constantly merge branches and then revert them using `svn revert ./ -R`. For some reason, reverting a repository with the recursive flag iterates through **every** file in our repo (thousands) and outputs a `Reverted [file]` message even if an `svn stat` shows only a **single** file actually has modifications that need to be reverted.

I'm using SVN 1.9.7 on Bash on Windows. Our servers are running SVN 1.9.9 on CentOS 7.3. My co-workers are running a mix of MacOS and Ubuntu. Most of us have experienced this problem, so I know it's not some weird issue with my particular machine.

Does anyone know a way to fix this? Googling it is difficult because the results are all just basic `svn revert` questions.

Comment: Actually, it appears that this behavior is dependent on the operating system. I see only the modified files being reverted in PowerShell, but but every file being reverted in Ubuntu. Interesting.

Comment: @WarlikeChimpanzee At least I know I'm not crazy. This is either a bug in SVN or some weird filesystem issue on certain flavors of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how svn works. If you want to revert all your source code it has to check the **entire source tree**. There's no cache of unsaved changes like you would have in an editor such as Visual Studio, because SVN just isn't that smart. For what it's worth, SVN `stat` and `diff` are also walking through the whole tree. I even imagine that `git revert --recursive` would show the same behavior, as it would need to check every file for any changes.

The only way to really prevent this is being smarter about only reverting what needs to be reverted. You can also cut time by piping to `/dev/null` (see 
[Why is outputting a string to the console slower than writing the same output to a text file?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-outputting-a-string-to-the-console-slower-than-writing-the-same-output-to-a-text-file)).

Comment: This doesn't happen on every machine, though. And it doesn't make sense that `svn stat` is smart enough to only display changed files but `svn revert` isn't. I understand that it needs to walk the entire source tree, but it doesn't need to _output_ anything for unchanged files.

Comment: I don't know why it would behave differently on different machines, but the excessive output seems to be simply an unfortunate behavior of `svn revert`. You can also use the `--quiet` flag. Is the desired behavior to see which files were actually modified and reverted?

Comment: @Sammy see above comment

Comment: I hadn't thought to use the quiet flag. I was hoping to only see the files with changes that were reverted, but I guess I can just use a combination of `svn stat` and `svn revert --quiet`. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Sammy you can also use `svn stat | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v -- "--- Changelist" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn revert` to revert and only holler about reverted (or missing) files as a command, btw. This will be faster on the disk reads than using `svn stat` and `svn revert`.